# What character is this? (yu2)

Tags: characters, character-identification, classical-chinese

The book "A First Course in Literature" from Shaddick uses this character:
[image: yu2]

In the vocabulary section it is explained as "TV to cross; to exceed". But I can't seem to find this character anywhere else (e.g. pinyin input). The closest matches are 逾 and 踰, the latter is also what we use at our university course instead. However, does anyone know anything about the original? Or is it just a mistake Shaddick made?

Comment: Historically they were variants of the same character. Now 逾 prevails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is 踰 (yú): exceed, transgress, cross over. It is a variant of 逾.

Characters are sometimes rendered differently. In this case, the phonetic is 俞 (yú), meaning "boat", and the bottom part is written similar to seal script style.

Originally, the 月 and 刂 in 俞 were 舟 (zhōu, boat) and 巛 (chuān, water), and the seal character is a transition in progress. Another evolutionary bastard is  (containing 舟 and 刂), with the same meaning.

[image: seal script]

Comment: Thank you. How did you input the characters by the way? The other form doesn't even have a pronunciation listed. How do search/input these?

Comment: Well,  has radical 足 and a phonetic with 11 strokes. If it is not possible to input with a regular method, you can always use the full Unicode character tables, for instance using "Special characters" in the menu on any OS X application.

You can, however, input the bastardized forms 兪 (yú) and derivatives like 楡 (yú), although  is apparently considered too rare to be included in regular pinyin input.

Comment: @langdi For special characters, I recommend the [搜狗输入法](http://pinyin.sogou.com/) (available both on windows and max). You can first input an 'U' to open the special input mode, where you can easily input spcial characters. For example, Uzuyu to input 踰 (zu 俞yu). There are many other usages. You can try it yourself! It'll be quite useful if you meet a character you don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not a mistake - just a simple variant:

## 《中华字海》页:1420:

[image: 《中华字海》页:1420]

## 字海:

[image: zisea]

(You notice how it says 非unicode字 right? So basically that means it's 打不出来的 or cannot be typed)

## 字海

[image: zisea]

(Here's "踰" with its definitions (bottom) and variants (right))

Answer (score 1):

踰[yú] 
to pass over；to cross；to go beyond；to transgress；to exceed；
[踰](http://dict.baidu.com/s?wd=%E8%B8%B0)
[踰](http://wapbaike.baidu.com/view/387594.htm?uid=A0449943A27A07A2F862A73EB3223E49&bd_page_type=1&ssid=0&from=844b&st=3&step=1&net=1&ldr=2)
异体字是形体不同而音义完全相同，古代在任何情况下都可以互相代替的字。
Variant form of different and identical ancient pronunciation, can replace each other in any case word.